# Check if page view is example node/page

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm having some trouble trying to put an if else statement into my "page.tpl.php". I don't remember (I did it in the past), how to check something like that,  but with some other page for example "www.example.com/home-2" or www.example.com/info . In my case is a page view, I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand you right...

#### In template.php

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object('node');

  if (isset($node) {
    $variables['node_type'] = $node->type;
  }
}
```

#### In page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($node_type == 'your_type') : ?>
  // something here for node type your_type
<?php endif; ?>
```

Additionally, you can simply add new template suggestions.

#### In template.php

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object('node'); 

  if (isset($node)) {
    $variables['node_type'] = $node->type;
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $node->type;
  }
}
```

After clearing your cache, you can create `page--node--(node_type).tpl.php` and put page specific markup for that node type there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first two anwsers did the trick.

I knew that i can do the theme_suggestions, but i didn't want to create more files so the menu_get_object worked like charm.

PD: I did it before but i couldn't remember how (i deleted those files).

THANKS!!!

EDIT: The solution in my case was to put the

```
  if (isset($node)) {
    $variables['node_type'] = $node->type;
  }
```

into the template.php

and then put my custom code with a conditional (for example):

```
<?php if ($is_front || $node_type == 'info_list'): ?>
```

into the page.tpl.php

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Okay cool. Mark as accepted if that is your solution.

Comment: If you combine the two answer to get your solution you can edit this answer with the full description of how do you solve your problem, is better for other users